# Pulling images from folder in jquery Supersized gallery not function in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, supersized

I am having a problem with a php script that pulls images from a folder and outputs to that a javascript gallery can display the images. Everything works fine in IE9 but no images display in IE7 or IE8. The php script code is:

```
    <?php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "images/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.JPG");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo "{image : './" . $image . "', title : '" .$image . "'},";
}
?>
```

The java script gallery can alternatively work by manually defining image sources and within the documentation it is mentioned that for IE7 and IE8 the removal of a final comma is necessary so I am guessing that the above script is adding one too many commas (i.e. the final comma). I have looked into using rtrim and chop but neither worked for me. I found some other sources mentioning implode but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is generated?

Answer (score 0):

The json you are producing is invalid...must be double quoted. I am assuming you are sending via ajax

Far simpler to use json_encode( $array  ) if running php 5 on server. Remove foreach loop and replace with:

```
$output=array();

foreach($images as $image)
{
$output[]=array( "image" => './" . $image . "', "title" => '" .$image . "');
}

echo json_encode( $output);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I found a solution that works (I don't know which version of php my webhost is running). Here is the code that works:

                                        <?php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "images/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.JPG");

//print each file name
$number = count($images);
$start = 0;

foreach($images as $image)
{
echo "{image : './" . $image . "', title : '" .$image . "'}";
if ($start < $number - 1)
 echo ", ";
$start = $start + 1;
}
?>